# How to convert objects to byte arrays in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, tcp

I need to convert some data into a custom defined packet format in flutter. To do this, I want to convert the individual data into a byte array which can be passed down the TCP socket.

I have converted the needed into an object but cannot find a solution to serialize it

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions might be converting your object into a JSON string and converting that string to bytes using `dart:convert`

```
// example object
final Example example =
    Example(name: "name", age: "age", address: "address");

// convert into bytes

// encode the object to a JSON string
String jsonString = jsonEncode(example);

// encode the string to a UTF-8 byte array
List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(jsonString);

// print the bytes for testing
print(bytes);
```

and don't forget to import

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert it into an array directly, like the way it might be represented in memory?

Comment: There is no built-in way to convert an object to a byte array in memory in Dart. You will need to use some form of serialization to encode the object into a binary format, and then use a ByteData or Uint8List to access the bytes.

Comment: How would I go about implementing this serialization? Do I need to manually convert the number into binary form and then stuff the Unint8list?

Comment: You may create utility functions or helper methods to convert your object into a bytes list.